# Is there a way to install clang multilib in linux, without gcc included?

Tags: ubuntu, clang, apt

I would like to build a program using clang on x86_64 and gerate the program to x86. So far so good, I just used this command:

`$ clang++ -m32 main.cpp`

However, I got some errors about headers and libraries.

This same situation with gcc, would be fixed by gcc-mutilib, but clang has not some multilib package.

If I install gcc-multilib, so I can do with clang -m32, although, I just want to install clang, excluding gcc package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xy deng's answer is on the right track. If you are compiling an x86 program on an x86 host, you just need to run

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

But if you are on an x86_64 host and want to cross-compile a program to x86, don't try installing `libc6-dev:i386`. You need the Apt package marked specifically for cross-compiling:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386-cross
```

[This AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947927/unable-to-locate-package-libc6-dev-i386) has more information about how Ubuntu and Apt organize these headers for cross-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is just libc6-dev:i386.